# ruby: convert http response codes to it's meaning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest-client, http-response-codes

how do you convert http response codes to it's meaning in ruby/rails.
I tried the (imaginary) `.to_words` method without success

```
(byebug) resp.code
201
(byebug) resp.code.to_words
"201 Created"
```

Comment: Can you accept my answer if you got what you need?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
Rack::Utils::HTTP_STATUS_CODES[200]
```